# Using a find() function with two vectors

Tags: find, julia

I am using the Julia programming language, and I know that you can use the find function in the following way:

```
a = [ 1 2 3 4 3 5 3 6 7 8 9 3 ]
find(a .== 3)
```

It will return: `3, 5, 7, 12`

Simple enough.

However, my question is, what if we want to replace the 3 in the above code to be a vector.

For example:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
b = [1 9 5 8]
```

The following syntax has not worked for me, but it conveys my idea. How would I do the following correctly?:

```
find (a .== b)
```

If we want it to return `1, 3`?

I know the matching function in R does this well, but I have a very large dataset, and R has not been handling it well.

Comment: why return not 1,5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way - use function [findin/2](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/collections/?highlight=intersect#Base.findin) :

```
julia> findin(b,a)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3

julia> findin(a,b)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 5
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot about that one.

Comment: Weirdly, I find that my version is more than 10x as fast as yours on Julia 0.5!? Can you confirm that?

Comment: @DNF, I am beginner in Julia, so I too would like to know =)

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain, but it seems like my version is faster for short vectors, while `findin` is faster for large vectors.

Comment: @DNF `findin` is significantly faster on my v0.5, for both small and large vectors of type `Int`, as long as both input vectors are the same size. But there is a lot of confounding variables here, e.g. length of `a` versus `b`, number of matches (on average), average location of matches etc... so it is a bit of a tricky one to test thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
julia>> find(x->x in b, a)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 5
```

or since you wanted `1, 3`:

```
julia> find(x->x in a, b)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
```

I also suggest that you use

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [1, 9, 5, 8]
```

instead of the version without commas, since column operations are more efficient than row operations in Julia.

Furthermore, it is more efficient to write `find(x->x==3, a)` than `find(a.==3)` since the latter will first create a full boolean vector and then search that, while the former will simply iterate through each element of `a` and perform the comparison.

**Edit:** If you are curious about the anonymous function notation, you should look up help for the `find` function. The point is that

```
find(f, a)
```

applies the function `f` to each element of `a` <s>before</s> while it is evaluating the `find` part.